# How to add jwt auth token when using Fine Uploader AngularJS directive

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm using the AngularJS Fine Uploader integration directive and I need to add a JWT authorization token to the header.  How do I do this?

Comment: You need to add a header to what? Why isn't the customHeaders option or method sufficient for this?

Comment: Are you suggesting the I call the core setCustomHeaders() function?  How would I reference the required uploader object from Angular controller code?  Or are you suggesting that I add the token to the fine uploader directive "request" configuration?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, I'm simply trying to extend the Angular integration example to use a token, not developing an app yet.  Thanks again.

Comment: Whichever approach suits your needs best.